# Laravel 5 multiple domains and not using url parameters

Tags: laravel

I've use 5 different sites with one domains like below.

- `mydomain.com/abc`
- `mydomain.com/def`
- `mydomain.com/ghi`
- `mydomain.com/jkl`
- `mydomain.com/mno`
- `mydomain.com/{site_id}`

And I want to connect new domain in one these sites.

What I mean is like this => `mydoain2.com = mydomain.com/ghi`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try forwarding your domain with masking. Here's the instruction on how to mask a domain: https://ph.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422

Here's the definition of web forwarding with masking: http://www.networksolutions.com/support/what-is-web-forwarding-and-masking/